# ReactJS Scroll Event Binding to function outside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table being generated by React by a function that fires render in a API callback. I am having trouble figuring out how I can find that function with the API call to the scrolling event of this div React makes. My understanding is components.js should ONLY be rendering, and that putting that API calling function in the component as a function is poor design. How do I make this binding happen?

```
React.createElement("div", {id: "queue-list-content", className: "queue-list-content", onScroll: this.handleScroll}

handleScroll: function(){
  //trying to call function that lives in the file with the rest of the API calling functions here
}
```